# Dynamically populate a QML Menu

Tags: c++, list, menu, qml

I'm working on an environment for running HP webOS apps. I need to read the Mojo.Menu and populate the QML Menu with the data taken from the javascript code.

For example from

```
            Mojo.Menu.prefsItem,
            {
                { label: $L("High Scores")
            },
```

I'd create the QML object

```
MenuItem {
    text: "High scores"
    onClicked: //some stuff
}
```

The list (either QStringList or QList ) would be provided by a Q_INVOKABLE function.

Is this possible to dynamically create such MenuItems and push them to the MenuLayout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
Qt.createQmlObject()
```

to dynamically create objects and afterward you can change their properties to the ones from your list. Look at [this article](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html) for more details on dynamic object creation.

To add these dynamically create items to the layout you create the layout first:

```
MenuLayout {
  id: customLayout
}
```

And then add dynamically created MenuItem

```
var menuComponent = Qt.createComponent("MenuItem.qml");
if(menuComponent.status == Component.Ready) {
  var createdMenu = menuComponent.createObject(customLayout);
  createdMenu.text = "Text from your QList";
}
```